# Disable Nuxt 3 preloader

Tags: nuxt3

I am using nuxt3 and don't know how to disable the default preloader.

I tried loading false in nuxt config but not working. I tried other methods also but nothing works for me properly for all the solution I tried it is taking the default whenever I start the server.

Comment: I wanted to know how to disable the nuxt 3 preloader

Comment: Is your app confgured ssr as false in nuxt.config? The preloader you meant is the animation loading logo of Nuxt right?

Comment: Apologies, I deleted my first comment. I was irrelevant

Comment: It is resolved now thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your nuxt config file. `spaLoadingTemplate: false` if ssr is set to false like this `ssr: false`